# How to change the creation of instance process? (ex : DI, Factory...)

Tags: c#, mef

During the compose process, MEF create instances of types imported using the constructor by default or the "ImportingConstructor".

I want to override this process of creation.

For example:

- Use DI pattern (using Unity)
- Use Factory pattern

Is it possible to do that with MEF?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: it is possible but requires effort.

Longer:

- In order to provide objects for imports (exported values), MEF operates on instances of [Export](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.composition.primitives.export) class. The exported value is retrieved using [Export.Value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.composition.primitives.export.value) property.
- If you wish to ad-hoc register particular instance of object within [CompositionContainer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.composition.hosting.compositioncontainer), you may do that using [AddExportedValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.composition.attributedmodelservices.addexportedvalue) or [ComposeExportedValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.composition.attributedmodelservices.composeexportedvalue).
- If you wish to intercept the process of creation of objects by MEF, this is totally different story.

We could simplify structure of MEF artifacts to:

- [ComposablePartCatalog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.composition.primitives.composablepartcatalog) provides [ComposablePartDefinition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.composition.primitives.composablepartdefinition) objects
- [ComposablePartDefinition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.composition.primitives.composablepartdefinition) objects are used by [ExportProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.composition.hosting.exportprovider) to create corresponding [ComposablePart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.composition.primitives.composablepart) objects
- [ComposablePart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.composition.primitives.composablepart) objects are responsible for producing actual exported values ([GetExportedValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.composition.primitives.composablepart.getexportedvalue))

All above classes are abstract. If you will analyze concrete classes used by MEF (e.g. use [CompositionContainer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.composition.hosting.compositioncontainer) with [TypeCatalog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.composition.hosting.typecatalog)), you will figure out that most of the implementation is internal and there is not much chances to inject custom logic. Still, there are some options.

You may implement proxy object for the specific, concrete MEF’s type. For instance, if you need to intercept all exported values the [CompositionContainer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.composition.hosting.compositioncontainer) provides:

- Create class, say CompositionContainerProxy (derived, from [CompositionContainer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.composition.hosting.compositioncontainer))
- Override [GetExportsCore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.composition.hosting.compositioncontainer.getexportscore) method, provide interception of exports

Sample:

```
public class CompositionContainerProxy : CompositionContainer
{
    protected override IEnumerable<Export> GetExportsCore(ImportDefinition definition, AtomicComposition atomicComposition)
    {
        IEnumerable<Export> exports = base.GetExportsCore(definition, atomicComposition);

        List<Export> proxies = new List<Export>();
        
        foreach (Export export in exports)
        {
            proxies.Add(new ExportProxy(export, this));
        }

        return proxies;
    }

    private object Intercept(object value)
    {
        return value; // TODO: Provide intercept logic.
    }

    private class ExportProxy : Export
    {
        private readonly Export export;

        private readonly CompositionContainerProxy proxy;

        public override ExportDefinition Definition
        {
            get { return export.Definition; }
        }

        internal ExportProxy(Export export, CompositionContainerProxy proxy)
        {
            this.export = export;
            this.proxy = proxy;
        }

        protected override object GetExportedValueCore()
        {
            object value = export.Value;

            return proxy.Intercept(value);
        }
    }
}
```

This way you may e.g. assure thread safety etc. See, e.g.: [Controller.cs](https://github.com/qube7/qcomposite/blob/master/Qube7.Composite/Controller.cs)

QComposite use such tricks for e.g. implementing hierarchical structure of controllers, export visibility scope etc.
https://qube7.com/guides/controller.html